# Select Distinct Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql> select * from product;

```
    +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+----------+
    | id | prod        | code  | name                | prodstat | 
    +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+----------+
    |  1 | ACCESSORIES | 2810  | Dish Rack           | 1        |
    |  2 | ACCESSORIES | 2816  | Saucer Rack         | 1        |
    |  3 | ACCESSORIES | 2830  | Drying Crate        | 1        |
    |  4 | ACCESSORIES | 2820  | Big Crate Cover     | 1        |
    |  5 | ACCESSORIES | 2826  | Scallop Crate Cover | 1        |
    |  6 | ACCESSORIES | 2828  | Mini Crate Cover    | 1        | 
    |  7 | ACCESSORIES | 2839  | Small Goblet Cover  | 1        |
    |  8 | ACCESSORIES | 2878  | Harvest Crate Cover | 1        |
    |  9 | CRATES      | 1688N | Big Crate New       | 1        |
    +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+----------+
    9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
     select distinct(prod, code, name) as Prod from product;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

need the result like :

```
|Prod|
|ACCESSORIES 2810 Dish Rack|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
select distinct prod, code, name
from product;
```

`distinct` is *not* a function.  `select distinct` is a clause and the `distinct` applies to all the arguments.

If you want to combine the three columns into a single column, use `concat()` or `concat_ws()`:

```
select distinct concat_ws(' ', prod, code, name) as Prod
from product;
```

(The `distinct` may not be necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Append column and give alias

```
select distinct (prod+' '+ code+' '+ name) as Prod from product;
```